# How to create zip archive using shutil.make_archive() without a file extension in python?

Tags: python, zip, archive

I need to create a zip archive with a custom extension of ‘.stz’ as this is the only file format accepted by the application it will be used in. Using shutil.make_archive the file always has the .zip file extension even if not specified by me. Currently just renaming it after creation. Is there a better way to do this?

```py
import os
import shutil

output = “file.stz”
dir_name = “files/“
zip_name = shutil.make_archive(‘tmp’, ‘zip’, dir_name)
os.rename(zip_name, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `shutil.register_archive_format` to register your own extension, but still compress it as a zip file.  This is more code but does allow you to skip your rename step.

```py
def stzCompress():
  pass
 
shutil.register_archive_format('stz', stzCompress, description='stz file')
```